# what is the meaning of long-term enduring?

Tags: meaning

As Zappos CEO Tony Hsieh recently shared with me, “If employees weren’t happy, they would not make customers happy. If customers weren’t happy, we wouldn’t be where we are today. We believe that if we get the culture right, then most of the other stuff, like delivering great service, **or building a long-term enduring brand will just happen naturally on its own**.”

I have problem in understanding last sentnece

Comment: It's "much of a muchness", redundant use of adjectives. A good specimen of long-term enduring headache-inducing [corporate jargon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_jargon).

Comment: I  think we can thank Mr Branson for the original concept and some journalist for translating it into corporate jargon.

Comment: I think the sentence would be much easier to read if there were a comma between *brand* and *will*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a clunky sentence because a) "building" and "happen naturally" are somewhat contradictory b) the meanings of "long-term" and "enduring" are so similar and c) "naturally" and "on its own" have similar meaning.

What the guy is tring to say is that a good brand is like a plant: if you create the right environment, it will grow on its own.

Comment: is it mean that if you create the right environment, then staff will be like delivering great service or long-term brand will be created  by itself?

Comment: Almost right:just replace or by and in your comment. The sequence of cause and effect is create right environment -> staff will be happy -> brand will grow on its own

Comment: what a difficult text! why do they write it with these kind of difficult sentences?

Comment: Journalists have to write a piece that's, say, 250 words long. Clarity is sometimes a hostage to getting the number of words right. This is a direct quote from Richard Branson: "Train people well enough so they can leave, treat them well enough so they don't want to." Clear and concise. Maybe that's why Richard Branson is very rich. The journalist, on the other hand, deserves to be very poor.

Comment: I don't think the journalist is to blame, because there are quotation marks around the sentences. It's a direct business babble quote from the CEO.